# React custom scrolling with ArrowKeys

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

I would like to create a custom scrolling animation for my comic viewer. I have recreated the sample code in a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-kfe1q
The problem I'm facing is, that the scrolling animation starts to "lag". And it isn't really possible to change the scroll speed and interval.
I'm trying to recreate a similar feeling like with this comic viewer: [Example](https://guya.moe/read/manga/Kaguya-Wants-To-Be-Confessed-To/2/1/)

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not even quite sure if the current example is the correct approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one possible solution to solve this

```
function useKeyPress(targetKey) {
  // State for keeping track of whether key is pressed
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);
  // If pressed key is our target key then set to true
  function downHandler(e) {
    if (e.key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(true);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  // If released key is our target key then set to false
  const upHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(false);
    }
  };
  // Add event listeners
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
    };
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount
  return keyPressed;
}

export function useUI() {
  const scrollDistance = 15;
  const ArrowUp = useKeyPress("ArrowUp");
  const ArrowDown = useKeyPress("ArrowDown");

  const k = useKeyPress("k"); // up
  const j = useKeyPress("j"); // down

  const w = useKeyPress("w"); // up
  const s = useKeyPress("s"); // down

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!(ArrowUp || ArrowDown || k || j || w || s)) {
      return null;
    }
    const scrollDirection = ArrowUp || k || w ? 1 : -1;
    let animationFrame = 0;
    let callback = () => {
      const pos = window.pageYOffset;
      window.scroll(0, pos - scrollDistance * scrollDirection);
      animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(callback);
    };
    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(callback);

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    };
  }, [ArrowUp, ArrowDown, k, j, w, s]);

  return null;
}
```